# Probability Theory and Counting with n

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 8 lumberjacks. Each lumberjack has 6 axes on him. Each of the axes is one of n models. The arrangement is such that each lumberjack does not carry more than one axe of the same model, and any two lumberjacks have at most one model in common. What is the minimum value of n that makes such an arrangement possible? Justify.

Comment: how do you guys think I should approach this?

Comment: edited problem with the answer I got doing it manually

Comment: still cant figure this out...

Comment: Isn't this pure (combinatorics) without a whiff of (probability) or (probability-theory)?

Answer (score 0):

How I would solve this?  I would draw 8 little stick-figure lumberjacks, with space around each.  I'd put an "A" next to the first and second lumberjack to denote they're both carrying model A.  Then a "B" next to the first and third.  Etc.

OK, I got to "X".  That's 24 models.  $24 = 8\times 6/2$.

Hmm, 8 lumberjacks, 6 axes each, 2 axes per model: $8\times 6/2$  models.  Makes sense.